# Is the Java Socket BufferedReader required check sum to check the data?

Tags: java, sockets, checksum

I would like to use the BufferedReader to read a serialized java object, is this reliable? or I need to implement to check sum to ensure the data? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to use an [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) for that (possibly wrapped over a [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html))?

Comment: A BufferedReader is for test, Java serialization use binary data and if you read it with a BufferedReader it would get corrupted.  The simplest solution is to use a BufferedInputStream which is designed for binary data and you shouldn't get corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `BufferedReader` to read a serialized object. Java has two kinds of I/O interfaces and classes:

- Streams (`InputStream` and `OutputStream` and everything that implements those) for reading and writing binary data.
- Readers and writers (`Reader` and `Writer`) for reading and writing text (binary data interpreted as characters).

Since serialized objects are binary data and not text, you cannot use a `Reader` to read serialized objects.

Answer (score 0):

TCP [guaranties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) data integrity. So you don't need additional check summing.

And the deserialization will fail with an exception when something goes wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. A serialized object should be read with `ObjectInputStream`, not `BufferedReader` or indeed anything else whatsoever.